# Spring Boot version 2.3.x src/test/resources removed

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

Seems in the Springboot version 2.3.x , they have removed the src/test/resources folder ,

I downloaded a skeleton from start.spring.io and did not see it , the current project structure is as below , in such a case how do I use a test specific property file , problem is even if I create a src/test/resources folder and put a test.property file in it , its not being found while I am running the test , Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Options I chose while generating the skeleton project in start.spring.io

[image]

Comment: It depends how you are reading that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a fair amount of research I found my answer , so the "resources" folder under src/test has been removed as part of the skeleton project that we could download from start.spring.io , but now they have included a new build task , well my project is in gradle but I am sure such is the case with Maven too , the name of this task in gradle is "processTestResources" , it copies whatever you have inside your `src/test/resources` folder to the `<Project_HOME>/build/resources/test` , which is in the classpath and you can access your resources as you could earlier , the only things is now you have to manually create the "resources" folder , now issue resolved , Thanks everyone for your inputs.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What IDE are you using ? Does the project use Maven ? In Eclipse with Maven if you right click on src/test and choose New -> Source Folder, and call it resources it should be created and added to the test classpath by Maven.

[image]

After placing the appropriate files in src/main/resources, and src/test/resources and running

```
    try(final Stream<String> fileStreamFromClasspath = Files.lines(Path.of(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("test.file").toURI())))
    {
        fileStreamFromClasspath.forEach(l -> System.out.println(l)); // NOSONAR
    }
    try(final Stream<String> fileStreamFromFilesystem = Files.lines(Path.of(("src/main/resources/test.file"))))
    {
        fileStreamFromFilesystem.forEach(l -> System.out.println(l)); // NOSONAR
    }
    try(final Stream<String> testFileStreamFromFilesystem = Files.lines(Path.of(("src/test/resources/test.file"))))
    {
        testFileStreamFromFilesystem.forEach(l -> System.out.println(l)); // NOSONAR
    }
```

Produces output:

```
This is the test test file.
This is the main test file.
This is the test test file.
```

Comment: I am using Eclipse 2020-06 with Gradle , do you know why this resources folder has been removed by default ? and what are the other options or are there any new options provided by Spring Boot to do the same.

Comment: I do not think it has been "removed" ... I suspect that it is related to the type of starter project options you have selected. But I would need to verify this. I do believe adding the source folder as I described in Eclipse will fix your issue with Gradle as well.

Comment: I just attached a snapshot of the options I chose while creating the project skeleton via start.spring.io , also I went back to Spring Boot version 2.1.17 , in start.spring.io , but its the same.

Comment: Can you show how you are attempting to read the file ? I will try and replicate your issue.